# Angular - Injecting locationProvider inside app constant

Tags: angularjs

I wish to inject location provider in the module constant, which is not possible

```
app.constant('foo', {
    hostName: <<$location.$$root>> //which is not possible.
}
```

so, I tried this:

```
app.provider('foo', ['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    this.data = {
        hostName: $locationProvider.$$root + ":1337"
    };
    this.$get = function() {
        return this.data;
    };
}]);
```

But again this didn't work, as `$locationProvider.$$root` is undefined.

Any solution/s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Module` constants in *AngularJS* are meant to register a value / object that can be accessed by a `Provider`, so basically you cannot go the other way, by trying to use `Provider` services within your `Constant` declaration.

A hack for such a situation would be to extract manually the value that you want pulled of, i.e. the *root page location*, from the `window.location` JavaScript object:

```js
app.constant('foo', {
    hostName: window.location.protocol + window.location.host // .host gives you the page hostname appended with the port used to render the page
}
```

Just remember that *plain JavaScript objects* provided by most web browsers are still out there when *AngularJS* cannot do the job.